# JQuery search function, why my dives doesnt hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Het guys,
im begginer using JQuery and the stuff is i have some displayed elements in divs.
this is the we site source:

```
<div id="application-list" class="row boxes">
    <h1>nowa3</h1>
    <div class="box col-md-4" id="Acrobat Reader 10">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3><img class="icon" src="/Acrobat%20Reader%2010.png" alt="Acrobat Reader 10" /> Acrobat Reader 10</h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="pull-right"> <a data-toggle="modal-loading" data-target="#application-launching-modal" target="application-launcher" href="/Acrobat%20Reader%2010.ica" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Run</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i want to do search function. i did put input fild and submit button and i setup code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var value = $('#appName').val();
        $('.col-md-4').each(function() {
            if ($(this).contains($(this), value)) {
                $(this).show();
            }
            else $(this).hide();
        });   
    });     
});
```

where `#button` its the id of subbmit button, `#appName` is the id of input field and `.col-md-4` is the class of divs i want to hide show when searching ?
It doesnt work when i want alert `$(this).id` it show nothing button click alert the value entered. whats wrong ?

```
<input type="text" id="appName"><button type="submit" id="button">Find</button>
```

its before:
`<div id="application-list" class="row boxes">`

Comment: i put only the part where div appears here is the part with button and input field. i will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery [`.contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/) checks if one element is a descendant of another element, and does not check if strings exists in an element, you should use `indexOf()` for that

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var value = $('#appName').val();
    $('.col-md-4').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).text().indexOf(value) != -1 ) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });   
});
```

or the `:contains` psuedo selector, which is not the same as `.contains()`

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    var value = $('#appName').val();
    $('.col-md-4').hide().filter(':contains('+value+')').show();
});
```

Comment: it works. nice thanks! got one more question what if i would like also to show div if the part of text is good. for example i have `Acrobat Reader 10` and the entered value is `adobe` i also want to show that div ?

Comment: How would `adobe` be related to `Acrobat Reader`, javascript doesn't have a list of software manufacturers built in? If you have two strings that don't match at all, you'll need to map them together with something, like an object. Otherwise, indexOf will match partial strings, and using `toLowerCase()` on both strings makes it case insesitive if you need that.

Comment: xD sorry i dont know what i was thinking i mean `acrobad` :P
thanks it works great :>